# Printing out array in the html with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of doubles (they turn into doubles eventually) in my controller that I am trying to print on my web page using ng-repeat, but I am unsure how to do so. The array is simply":

```
vm.calorieArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

where vm is the alias of my controller.

In my html I have a div that looks like this that is attempting to print it out:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in vm.calorieArray">
    {{value}}<br />
</div>
```

but nothing shows up on the page. Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: looks right to me, it's probably something else, you need to post more.  Did you declare ng-app?

Comment: what are you seeing in console?

Comment: Use ng-repeat="value in calorieArray" instead of ng-repeat="value in vm.calorieArray"

Comment: @Shohel, i think OP used _controller as_ syntax, so _$scope_ not needed

Comment: write plunker or fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be because of duplicate values not being allowed in the ng-repeat. See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cK6WJkYcNTKYumLxkqVY?p=preview) for an example of the issue. (Open up your dev console to see the JS errors)  The description of the error can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=value%20in%20array&p1=number:0&p2=0).

In short you should use 'track by $index' as in the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="value in calorieArray track by $index">
    {{value}}<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle with your example working: http://jsfiddle.net/JKBbV/743/

The controller is as simple as:

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.values = [0,0,0,0,0.1];
});
```

My guess is that your app is not initialising correctly, or you aren't properly binding your array to the `$scope`.

Comment: if you use not old angular version you get error: _Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: value in values, Duplicate key: number:0, Duplicate value: 0_ : http://jsfiddle.net/JKBbV/742/